# Spring first request very slow

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I have application in Spring Boot. After initialization of Spring Boot with embeded tomcat, the first response is very slow. How can I fix it? Has spring boot any warmup command/mode?  I am thinking  too about connection with database and I am wondering  about connection database, probably spring connects with Postgres during first request.

Comment: What is your first request? Does it access the database? Are you loading data in a cache?

Comment: First request is  access the database, i am just creating new item on database.

Comment: so that's the reason why it runs slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use ApplicationRunner or CommandlineRunner to run something on startup:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner